# Cant find pom in allure reports

Tags: protractor, allure

I looked at below post to setup allure reports for protractor jasmine.

But I can't find pom.xml in '\node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter'.
[Jasmine-allure-reports contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1je.png)

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine.

It should work. I will update if it works.